# What's the quickest way to multiply multiple cells by another number?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

If I have a block of cells such as A1:D5, what's the quickest way of multiplying each cell by another number, 1.1 using Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Do you want to retain the original values in A1:D5?
Where do you want the result?
Do you want a value for each of the cells in A1:D5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you asking how to do it in excel or how to do it in a VBA application?  If you just want to do it in excel, [here is one way.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Multiply-numbers-9d152e08-002c-47a1-a88a-264483e68fa1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 40):

1. Enter the multiplier in a cell
2. Copy that cell to the clipboard
3. Select the range you want to multiply by the multiplier
4. (Excel 2003 or earlier) Choose **Edit** | **Paste Special** | **Multiply**

   (Excel 2007 or later) Click on the Paste down arrow | **Paste Special** | **Multiply**

Comment: For this method, you have to create an equivalent shaped range where each cell contains the multiplier and then Paste Special | Multiply the original range onto the multiplier range, I think

Answer (score 6):

To multiply a column of numbers with a constant(same number), 
I have done like this.

Let `C2` to `C12` be different numbers which need to be multiplied by a single number (constant). Then type the numbers from `C2` to C12.

In `D2` type 1 (unity) and in `E2 type formula =PRODUCT(C2:C12,CONSTANT)`. SELECT RIGHT ICON TO APPLY. NOW DRAG `E2` THROUGH `E12`. YOU HAVE DONE IT.

```
C       D       E=PRODUCT(C2:C12,20)

25  1   500
30      600
35      700
40      800
45      900
50      1000
55      1100
60      1200
65      1300
70      1400
75      1500
```

Comment: By far the simplest and most elegant solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

Put the number you want to multiply by in a cell that is not in your range. Select the cell and "Copy" it to the clipboard.
Next, select the Range A1:D5, and from the menu choose Edit|Paste Special.
A dialog box will appear. In the "Operation" area, select "Multiply" and click "OK".

Comment: I've been doing this backwards: filling a range with the multiplier and Paste Special-ing on to that (see comment to question above). Thanks for this better method

Answer (score 4):

Select `Product` from formula bar in your answer cell.

Select cells you want to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be a macro, then just put `=A1*1.1` into (say) D7, then drag the formula fill handle across, then down.

Comment: and then, if desired, copy the new cells and paste-special-values into the old range (or in place), then delete the cells you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the answers above says: " then drag the formula fill handle."  This KEY feature is not mentioned in MS's explanation, nor in others here.  I spent over an hour trying to follow the various instructions, to no avail.  This is because you have to click and hold  near the bottom of the cell just right (and at least on my computer that is not at all easy) so that a sort of "handle" appears.  Once you're luck enough to get that, then carefully slide ["drag"] your  cursor down to the lowermost of the cells you want to be multiplied by the  constant.  The products should show up in each cell as you move down.  Just dragging down will give you only the answer in the first cell and a lot of white space.